# How to implement kezong / fat-aar-android in android project?

Tags: android

I have gone through my gradle versions, AGP : 7.0.3, Gradle-wrapper 7.2, JDK 11, Thank you for your help.

```
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'SampleDemo'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not find com.kezong.fat-aar:1.3.8:.
         Required by:
             project :
```